# mysql query - nested with group by

Tags: mysql

I want to create a query that returns the amount of leads that came in for each hour of the day, as well as the sales count for each hour.  The result is to be 24 rows, 1 for each hour of the day.

I have a query that works for either/or,  but how do I combine with one query?

The table 'mytable' is:

```
id  datetime  status 
--------------------
```

Here's the query for total:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime, '%H') AS Hour, 
 count(id) AS Count

FROM mytable

GROUP BY Hour
```

and here's the query for "sold":

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime, '%H') AS Hour, 
 count(id) AS Count

FROM mytable

WHERE status='Sold'    

GROUP BY Hour
```

So I want the result to return something that looks like this:

```
Hour Count  Sold
----------------
0     5      2
1     4      0
2     9      6
.
.
.
.
23    6      1
```

I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you can use sum with expression,it will result as boolean ,this will give you the count where status is sold

```
SELECT 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime, '%H') AS Hour, 
    COUNT(id) AS Count,
    SUM(status='Sold' ) sold
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Hour
```

Comment: +1 for doing the check in the SUM() aggregate :) don't see people do that very often anymore and its a simple solution thats to the point :)

Comment: Agree @JohnRuddell  - I love this solution and gladly accept my downvote to learn this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN status='Sold' THEN FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime, '%H') ELSE 0 END AS Hour, 
  ,FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime, '%H') AS Hour2 ,count(id) AS Count
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY Hour
```

Comment: this is not a good answer as there can be none sold at a particular hour. add an else in your case :) ... also I'm not sure your logic in the select will even do what the OP requested.

Comment: why else ? first i want just status is sold ,

Comment: thats not what the OP requested though.. look at his desired output. he wants it ordered by hour asc... hour 1 has 0 Sold. your next part is a bunch of additional computations you don't need to make (for the hour again) and you don't have a column for the count of how many have been `Sold`

Comment: your query should look like this.  `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime, '%H') AS Hour, CASE WHEN status='Sold' THEN SUM(status) ELSE 0 END AS Sold, COUNT(id) AS Count
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY Hour`